# Is "epicharia" or "epikaria" a Greek word?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, greek

[I recently requested a word from Greek which means, "knowing when to break the rules".](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2241/what-ancient-greek-word-or-idea-signifies-a-knowledge-of-when-to-break-the-rules) The question I asked generated a lot of fine responses, but unfortunately it could not remind me of the original word that I had heard from my friend.

Even more recently, I asked my friend which word he had used, and he replied with *epikaria* or *epicharia*. However, we are both having a hard time finding this word in any dictionary. It does, interestingly enough, show up on Google searches.

Does Greek have the word *epikaria* or *epicharia*?

Comment: Could have it been [epikeia](http://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/epikeia), by any chance? (See also [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epikeia) definition.)

Comment: @Rafael Thanks, Rafael! I'll look over that one closely.

Comment: @Rafael Επιείκεια was actually already suggested in the original question. As I wrote there as well, I eventually think that this is indeed the term.

Comment: @Helen I'm pretty close to accepting that answer in my original question. Thanks a lot for your helpful feedback.

Comment: Sorry, it seems my brain keeps undigging possible candidates... Επιορκία - oathbreaking.

Answer (score 7):

#### Could the word have been ἐπίκαιρα (epícaera)?

This is the neuter plural of the adjective ἐπίκαιρος (epícaerus, second declension two-termination). It could also potentially be an adverbial form, though I'd expect ἐπίκαιρον instead for that.

This adjective means either "at just the right time", "for only a certain time", or in medicine, "very serious". It comes from the noun καιρός meaning "the right time", suggested in a (now sadly deleted) answer to the other question.

This is the closest word I can think of which pertains to timing.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No :) I'm a native Greek speaker with some knowledge of ancient Greek and neither epicharia nor epikaria rings a bell, while Google doesn't return anything that can lead to associations. (Epicharia seems to be the name of a saint, but its form can easily be recognized as, precisely, a constructed name.)

Comment: What is your opinion of the other proposed answer: "ἐπίκαιρα"?

Comment: @brianpck I think there is a point there, but couldn't think/find a word with the OP meaning.

Comment: @brianpck For the record, I think that επιείκεια is most probably the word (wrote so at the original question as well).

Comment: I was surprised to see many down votes, so I edit this to keep only the strict answer to OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Another similar-sounding word with similar meaning: ἐπιορκία (pr. epiorkia). Oathbreaking, false swearing.